# Set precision and delimiter for number at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I set both precision and delimiter for number in Rails?

For example, I have a float number 1000.0 and want to get 1 000,00

My locale file:

```
number:
  format:
    delimiter: ' '
    precision: 2
    separator: ','
```

I used helpers methods:

1. number_with_precision returns

   ```
   1000,00
   ```
2. number_with_delimiter returns

   ```
   1 000,0
   ```
3. both number_with_precision and number_with_delimiter return

   ```
   1 000,0
   ```
4. localize returns

   ```
   Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. 1000.0 given.
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`number_to_currency 1000.0, unit: ''`

Answer (score 9):

[number_with_precision](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_with_precision) has a delimiter and separator option.

`<%= number_with_precision(1000.0, precision: 2, delimiter: ' ', separator: ',') %>
=> 1 000,00`

Answer (score 1):

Use number_to_currency and strip the leading whitespace

`number_to_currency(1000.0, unit: '')[1..-1]
=>
"1 000,00"`